# SQL classic asp - conditional statement

Tags: sql, asp-classic

I am not an expert at SQL and have indentified a bug in some existing classic asp code of mine such that it does not work in all situations. 
I am hopeful somebody with some excellent sql experience can help me with writing the more complex situation of when both situations occur such that

`If intItemType = SV_ITEM_TYPE_MATRIX` then this part of the SQL is used

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN usd_matrixSets MS " &_
    "ON MS.itemID = SI.itemID " &_
```

But when `intItemType <> SV_ITEM_TYPE_MATRIX`  then it is ignored.

As you can see I have written code for either/or situations but this does not actually cover me for the situation of when both can occur .

Here is the code:

```
If intItemType = SV_ITEM_TYPE_MATRIX Then   
    strSQL = "SELECT SI.itemID, itemType, itemText, minimumValue, maximumValue, dataType, MS.matrixSetType, MS.matrixSetID " &_
             "FROM usd_SurveyItem SI " &_
             "LEFT OUTER JOIN usd_matrixSets MS " &_
             "ON MS.itemID = SI.itemID " &_
             "WHERE surveyID = " & intSurveyID &_
             " AND itemType " &_
             "In(" & SV_ITEM_TYPE_TEXTAREA & "," &_
                    SV_ITEM_TYPE_SINGLE_LINE & "," &_
                    SV_ITEM_TYPE_DATE & "," &_
                    SV_ITEM_TYPE_CHECKBOXES & "," &_
                    SV_ITEM_TYPE_RADIO & "," &_
                    SV_ITEM_TYPE_DROPDOWN & "," &_
                    SV_ITEM_TYPE_MATRIX & "," &_
                    SV_ITEM_TYPE_UPLOAD_FILE & ")" &_
             " AND pageID = " & intPageNumber &_
             " ORDER BY pageID, SI.orderByID "

        else            
    strSQL = "SELECT SI.itemID, itemType, itemText, minimumValue, maximumValue, dataType" &_
             " FROM usd_SurveyItem SI " &_
             "WHERE surveyID = " & intSurveyID &_
             " AND itemType " &_
             "In(" & SV_ITEM_TYPE_TEXTAREA & "," &_
                    SV_ITEM_TYPE_SINGLE_LINE & "," &_
                    SV_ITEM_TYPE_DATE & "," &_
                    SV_ITEM_TYPE_CHECKBOXES & "," &_
                    SV_ITEM_TYPE_RADIO & "," &_
                    SV_ITEM_TYPE_DROPDOWN & "," &_
                    SV_ITEM_TYPE_MATRIX & "," &_
                    SV_ITEM_TYPE_UPLOAD_FILE & ")" &_
             " AND pageID = " & intPageNumber &_
             " ORDER BY pageID, SI.orderByID "      

        end if
```

My problem is that sometimes I have both   SV_ITEM_TYPE_MATRIX and others all at the same time within my database. How can I rewrite this code?

Comment: You also have a risk of SQL injection

Comment: You should consider using command parameters: forums.asp.net/t/886691.aspx/1

Comment: "GROUP BY" would do it - but which item type would you want to show?

Answer (score 2):

You should always do the LEFT JOIN, and just let the extra values (`MS.matrixSetType` and `MS.matrixSetID`) be `NULL` when it's not `SV_ITEM_TYPE_MATRIX`.

Something like (I'll use parameters to avoid SQL injection vulnerabilities):

```
SELECT 
    SI.itemID, itemType, itemText, minimumValue, maximumValue, dataType, 
    MS.matrixSetType, MS.matrixSetID 
FROM usd_SurveyItem SI
LEFT OUTER JOIN usd_matrixSets MS ON 
    MS.itemID = SI.itemID 
    AND @intItemType = SI.itemType
WHERE
    surveyID = @intSurveyID  
    AND itemType IN (
       ...
    )
    AND pageID = @intPageNumber 
ORDER BY 
    pageID, SI.orderByID
```

Comment: Thanks - this seems what I want - but can you show me the exact code? I am not so good with these complex statements. Regards.

Comment: I must add that testing for NULL in the SQL statement will tell you from your data what type of data it is. In T-SQL ISNULL is extremely handy.

Comment: Thanks. I am nearly there. Here is my new code: <br>SELECT SI.itemID, itemType, itemText, minimumValue, maximumValue, dataType, MS.matrixSetType, MS.matrixSetID FROM usd_SurveyItem SI LEFT OUTER JOIN usd_matrixSets MS ON MS.itemID = SI.itemID AND intItemType = 12 WHERE surveyID = 217 AND itemType In(6,7,8,9,10,11,12,17) AND pageID = 1 ORDER BY pageID, SI.orderByID but i get this error: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Join expression not supported.

Comment: Dear All - Can someone spell out the answer much more clearly for me please? I am not sure that I am close to the answer after all! Apologies but my knowledge of complex SQL is not that good. With regards!

Comment: @user187108: a) please don't include code in comments they are unreadable, b) I'm not sure how this answer could be any clearer.

Comment: @user187108 - Your code is wrong. The 2nd JOIN clause should be "AND 12 = SI.ItemType". As for the "join expression not supported" - not sure what that's about. I don't really know Access (but it could be because of the undefined intItemType in the JOIN clause that you have wrong).

Comment: Thanks for the advice - so how do I show you the new code that I have and the error that results ..

Comment: Thanks Mark - this is so appreciated!

Comment: @Mark Brackett:But using the code I get the following SELECT SI.itemID, itemType, itemText, minimumValue, maximumValue, dataType, MS.matrixSetType, MS.matrixSetID FROM usd_SurveyItem SI LEFT OUTER JOIN usd_matrixSets MS ON (MS.itemID = SI.itemID AND 12 = SI.itemType) WHERE surveyID = 217 AND itemType In(6,7,8,9,10,11,12,17) AND pageID = 1 ORDER BY pageID, SI.orderByID Active Server Pages error 'ASP 0115' Unexpected error / A trappable error (C0000005) occurred in an external object. The script cannot continue running

Comment: @user187108 - that doesn't sound like a SQL/Access problem. That sounds more like a COM component going kablooey.